# Install Passenger on Scientific Linux 6.5 via RPM

Tags: rpm, scientific-linux

According to [this documentation](http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/01/04/phusion-passenger-native-packages-for-redhatfedoracentos/) passenger is a native yum package since RHEL6.

**Linux version and type**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/*release
Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon)
Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon)
```

**Yum install Passenger**

*Before installing RPM*

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum search passenger
Loaded plugins: security
sl                                                       | 3.6 kB     00:00
sl-security                                              | 3.0 kB     00:00
sl-security/primary_db                                   | 4.5 MB     00:17
sl6x                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
sl6x-security                                            | 3.0 kB     00:00
sl6x-security/primary_db                                 | 4.5 MB     00:19
Warning: No matches found for: passenger
No Matches found
```

*After installing RPM*

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install mod_passenger -y
Loaded plugins: security
sl                                                       | 3.6 kB     00:00
sl-security                                              | 3.0 kB     00:00
sl-security/primary_db                                   | 4.5 MB     00:19
sl6x                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
sl6x-security                                            | 3.0 kB     00:00
sl6x-security/primary_db                                 | 4.5 MB     00:17
Setting up Install Process
No package mod_passenger available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

As passenger does not to be included in the yum repository, an attempt was done to install it using RPM, although this only should be required in case of RHEL 5 according the documentation.

**RPM install**

The RPM has been installed.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/5/passenger-release.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/5/passenger-release.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.w5Z8Il: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 71e042e4: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:passenger-release      ########################################### [100%]
```

**Yum install after installing RPM**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install mod_passenger -y                        Loaded plugins: security
http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/6.5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/6.5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.hmdc.harvard.edu/mirrors/passenger/rhel/6.5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: passenger. Please verify its path and try again
```

**Yum search**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum search passenger
Loaded plugins: security
http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/6.5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/6.5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.hmdc.harvard.edu/mirrors/passenger/rhel/6.5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: passenger. Please verify its path and try again
```

**6.5 directory unavailable**

It appears that the 6.5. directory does not exist.

[image]

**Question**

How to Install Passenger on Scientific Linux 6.5 via RPM?

Comment: What do you get for `yum search passenger`? You probably just have the wrong package name.

Comment: @terdon The output of the command has been added to the question.

Comment: The yum repo file for this looks like it's just takes the version from your distro and plunks it into the search that `yum` does assuming that the versions are there.

Comment: @slm The command has been executed on a new VM, the output has been added to the question and it appears that `passenger` is not a native package on 6.5

Comment: Yup, so you can either build the mod yourself or point the yum cfg file for this repo to the prev version, ie 6.3

Comment: @slm After replacing `$releasever` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo`, executing `sudo yum search passenger` the package is found and it is possible to install it aside from some dependency issues.

Comment: @slm Perhaps you could post an answer because the advice solved the issue

Comment: Good, so you could use it in this manner until the repo releases a 6.5. I'd be tempted to let them know about it.

Comment: I will later today, I'm on my tablet and typing long form is too painful ☺

Comment: @slm Solving the dependency issues took some time. Shall I post an answer containing that solution to this question as well or should I open a new question regarding the dependency issues?

Comment: By all means, go for it.

Comment: @slm I will post a kind of subanswer after you have posted an answer because without that it was not possible to see dependency issues. I will wait to later today.

Comment: You could also use the passenger gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/passenger

Comment: @Jan Yes that is possible, but I would like to install it using RPM as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advices of @terdon and @slm the package could be found (yum search passenger) by executing the following commands:

```
sudo rpm --import http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-stealthymonkeys.asc && \
sudo yum -y install http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/6/passenger-release.noarch.rpm && \
sudo sed -i 's/\$releasever/6.3/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo
```

However, some dependency issues occurred after installing passenger:

```
Error: Package: 1:rubygem-passenger-native-3.0.19-1.el6.x86_64 (passenger)
           Requires: libev.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:rubygem-passenger-native-3.0.19-1.el6.x86_64 (passenger)
           Requires: libev
Error: Package: 1:rubygem-passenger-3.0.19-1.el6.x86_64 (passenger)
           Requires: rubygem(fastthread) >= 1.0.1
Error: Package: 1:rubygem-passenger-3.0.19-1.el6.x86_64 (passenger)
           Requires: rubygem(rack)
```

These could be solved by executing the following commands:

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/libev-4.03-3.el6.x86_64.rpm && \
sudo yum -y install rubygems && \
for p in rubygem-fastthread-1.0.7-2.el6.x86_64 rubygem-rack-1.1.0-2.el6.noarch; do sudo rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/${p}.rpm; done && \
sudo yum -y install mod_passenger
```